# Qualys API Integration with Python

Tags: python, api, curl, qualys

Having spent the past few days trying to get the Qualys API to work with python, I am usually running into errors such as 401 and errors of that sort, due to the fact that python code examples say they are unsupported.

Since Qualys API is written with curl, I used [Curl.trillworks.com](https://curl.trillworks.com/#) to convert curl to python.

The code I used was: (curl)

```
curl -u "USERNAME:PASSWD" -H "X-Requested-With: Curl" -X "POST" -d
"action=create&title=My+Dynamic+Search+List&global=1&published_dat
e_within_last_days=7&patch_available=1"
"https://qualysapi.qualys.com/api/2.0/fo/qid/search_list/dynamic/"
```

and converted it into python:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'Curl',
}

data = [
  ('published_date_within_last_days', '7'),
  ('patch_available', '1'),
]

response = requests.post('https://qualysapi.qualys.com/api/2.0/fo/qid/search_list/dynamic/', headers=headers, data=data, auth=('USRNAME', 'PASSWORD'))
print (response)
```

And got a 401 response. Any ideas or any more clarifications I should add? Thanks

**UPDATE - 12/27/2020**

Its been a while since I had this problem. Not sure what the issue was but for anyone else having the same issue, I would recommend plugging in the CURL statements into tools like Insomnia or Postman which convert these into any language. That would help you get more accurate conversions.

Comment: Any reason not to use a module built for that purpose - [`qualysapi`](https://github.com/paragbaxi/qualysapi)?

Comment: I was looking at PyCurl but I just wanted to know what was wrong with the code I had written.

Comment: @zwer I don't think `qualysapi` is official.

Answer (score 1):

I assume username/password input is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Qualys API v10.16](https://www.qualys.com/docs/qualys-api-vmpc-user-guide.pdf), you can try Session Based Authentication by passing `QualysSession` cookies after performing login.

Post login request:

```
login_api = api_url+"/api/2.0/fo/session/"

myheaders = { 'X-Requested-With': 'python'}
myparams  = { "action" : "login", "username" : api_username,  "password" : api_password} 

r_login =  requests.post(login_api, headers=myheaders, params=myparams)

print(r_login.status_code)
print(r_login.cookies.get_dict())
```

After getting the login ok response you can pass the cookies as `dict` ins subsequent `get` or `post`:

```
mycookies =  r_login.cookies.get_dict()
r_new =  requests.post(another_url, headers=myheaders, params=myparams, cookies=mycookies)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues, your data is list while it should be json and second is you should use HTTPBasicAuth while making requests with username and password.

Below is the corrected code

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth


headers = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'Curl',
}

data = {
  'published_date_within_last_days': '7',
  'patch_available': '1',
}

response = requests.post('https://qualysapi.qualys.com/api/2.0/fo/qid/search_list/dynamic/', headers=headers, data=data, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('USRNAME', 'PASSWORD'))
print (response)
```